# How to best support multiple versions of python while keeping a list of dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I have a project I maintain, which has it's `setup.py` and a `requirements.txt` files. My installation flow is:

- `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- `pip install -e .`

That way I now I'm developing on the tested versions I'm used to. I wanted to start supporting new version (old: 3.6, new: 3.7) and got an issue with a dependency - the `ipdb` I want (0.13.7) needs `ipython==7.17` (when running python3.7) which needs python>3.6, i.e. my python3.6 is no longer supported.

**What would be the best way for supporting multiple python versions, when some dependencies clash?**

---

My thoughts are:

1. relaxing the requirement - i.e. changing the `requirements.txt` entry to `ipython>=7.15`. Problem: my `requirements.txt` is the `pip freeze` output, and manually changing it seems a bad practice
2. having a `requirements.txt` file per python version. Problem: Didn't see anyone does this + I don't like the thought of multiple files

Comment: I would say relaxing the requirement and using some Automation testing like https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ on your project would be the way to go.

Comment: You can have per-python requirements. Everyone does that. This is how I do, for example: https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/devscripts/requirements/requirements_pg8000.txt or https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/devscripts/requirements/requirements_tests.txt